# Problem with TexLive installation on Fedora 17 to 20

Tags: installing, texlive, linux, perl

I just upgraded to Fedora 17 and tried to install TeX Live, as usually, by downloading the install script, `install-tl` from `tug.org`. When I run

```
./install-tl
```

I get this output:

```
[giorgos@desktopCosmos install-tl-20120511]$ ./install-tl

Can't locate loadable object for module Digest::MD5 in @INC
(@INC contains: ./tlpkg /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 198
Compilation failed in require at tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 198.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 198.
Compilation failed in require at ./install-tl line 53.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./install-tl line 53.
```

`MD5.pm`, however is already installed i.e. when I run

```
[giorgos@desktopCosmos install-tl-20120511]$ perl -MCPAN -e 'install Digest::MD5'

Going to read '/home/giorgos/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 14 Jun 2012 00:27:03 GMT
Digest::MD5 is up to date (2.52).
```

Also, I tried to copy `MD5.pm` to `@INC`' s path and still I get the same result.

The problem persists in Fedora 20 as well.

Answer (score 19):

You need the package `perl-Digest-MD5`

```
sudo yum install perl-Digest-MD5
```

After a Fedora 20 default installation, I also found that I needed wget

```
sudo yum install wget
```

Now you can install

```
sudo ./install-tl
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works. At home, on my own CentOS build, I have not needed to add anything. At work, it seems they installed an old image disk on my comp where this perl library was missing. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The approach described [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/TeXLive) appears promising.

It goes as follows (for Fedora 17):

```
# rpm -i http://jnovy.fedorapeople.org/texlive/2012/packages.fc17/texlive-release.noarch.rpm
```

> The package contains repo file for yum which contains TeX Live with binaries. After installing the release package do:

```
# yum clean all
# yum install texlive
```

> if you don't have texlive already installed. Otherwise you can update your old TeX Live 2007 installation like:

```
# yum clean all
# yum update
```

Comment: That is what I always do and it works very well. Also you can install all of TeXLive by doing `yum install texlive-scheme-full`, it takes a couple of hours, but you have everything. It saves you the headache of doing the manual installation, the drawback is that you need to be Administrator (or at least `sudo`-`yum` user).

Answer (score 2):

I installed Tex Live on Fedora 17 today and I didn't encountered any problems.

I called the installer like this:

```
$ perl install-tl
```

Also I didn't need to install any extra perl packages and I don't any have perl packages installed via CPAN. I used just the perl like it is installed with a default Fedora installation.

Perhaps you are using a local perl installation under `/usr/local` and/or your CPAN state is messed up. Or your upgrade left out some important perl packages.

Comment: thank you for your answer, even after a fresh install of fedora 17 I had the same problem. Anyway, I managed to overcome the problem after all but I really don't know how I did it; a bit of luck and careful reading of the error messages... anyway, problem solved

Comment: you surely had perl-Digest-MD5 installed has a dependency from another package, the solution is to install it as Nate Iverson suggested

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well, and managed to get the installer to start if I first installed `Digest::MD5` via cpan and then ran `perl install-tl`.

However, I had to run those as root, because otherwise the install script wouldn't let me install TL to the hard drive (because of obvious permissions problems).

This is what I did to make it work:

```
sudo cpan install Digest::MD5
sudo perl ./install-tl
```

Answer (score 1):

Either install the TeX system that comes with the distribution, or install Jindrich Novy's [texlive](http://jnovy.fedorapeople.org/texlive/) repository for a newer version. Note that Fedora 18 has the above already integrated, so perhaps a better solution is to just upgrade.